# Why is the syntax of this copy command incorrect?

Tags: command-line, cmd.exe

In Windows 10 the following command:

```
copy /y libPitchExtraction.so C:\Users\adams_000\CODE\C++\PitchExtraction\android-armv7\android-build\libs\armeabi-v7a\libPitchExtraction.so
```

causes the error:

> The syntax of the command is incorrect.

Putting the last parameter in quotes resolves the problem, however it's not possible for me to do so, as this command is auto-generated and I don't know how to change it (part of Qt Android build toolchain).

I could change the location of the project, if it helps, but I don't know what is causing the trouble in the first place, since there are no white spaces or no special characters, at least due to this guide (http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php )

Comment: It may be related to the `++` in your directory structure...?

Comment: Correctly assumed, moving the project so that the "C++" folder is left out solved the issue. Any idea why that is the case? As far as I knew, "+" should not have any special meaning.

Comment: A single `+` might not, a double, however, I don't know :) It may be assuming some kind of concatenation or multiple locations (the "source" for `copy` has `+` as a way of copying multiple files)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### As far as I know, `+` should not have any special meaning

`+` does have special meaning for `copy`. It indicates that files should be combined as part of the copy process.

> To combine files, specify a single file for the destination, but multiple files as the source. To specify more than one file use wildcards or list the files with a `+` in between each (`file1+file2+file3`)

- The `+` should probably only be recognised as a combine operator when it is at the beginning of a filename, so your particular case may be a bug in the command line processing for `copy`.

---

#### Syntax

> `COPY [options] [/A|/B] source [/A|/B] [+ source2 [/A|/B]...]
>   [destination [/A|/B]]`
>
> `COPY source1 + source2.. destination [options]`

...

> Combining files
>
> To combine files, specify a single file for the destination, but
>   multiple files as the source. To specify more than one file use
>   wildcards or list the files with a + in between each
>   (file1+file2+file3).
>
> When copying multiple files in this way the first
>   file must exist or else the copy will fail, a workaround for this is
>   COPY null + file1 + file2 dest1

Source - [copy](http://ss64.com/nt/copy.html)

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [copy](http://ss64.com/nt/copy.html) - Copy one or more files to another location.